# functional non-destructive array sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Apart for the native way of cloning an array and then sorting it in place, is there an algorithm and existing implementation that is more suited for non-destructive sorting?

Need to sort an array of floats into a new array without changing the source. My search results were rather thin since most of the literature is focused on reducing the memory requirements with in-place sorting.

**Using the native `sorted = [].slice().sort()` works fine**. This question is about understanding if there are other performant sorting implementations when memory constraints are removed since a new array is needed anyway.

Comment: "Is there any existing functional sort implementation available? " --- How about `[].slice().sort()`?

Comment: There is no preferred algorithm. It depends on how you want to use it. I’d go with `.slice().sort()`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The only *native* sort is `Array.prototype.sort`, which, as you know, mutates the array. The canonical way to make it non-mutable is to use `.slice().sort()`. Do you have some issue with that approach? If so, why, and what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: It might be worth microbenchmarking the performance of `.slice()` vs creating a new array and pushing elements individually. That might be why the libraries you listed don't use an algorithm that builds the resulting array sequentially.

Comment: The question already states that `.slice().sort()` works fine. Without micro-optimizing anything, I am curious to know if there is a sorting algorithm that is better for non-destructive sorts. I could not find out since the literature is focused on the opposite in-place sorting.

Comment: You should probably explain what you mean "a better way"; better in which way?

Comment: If you're asking for a preferred algorithm, you HAVE to specify what criteria you're measuring it by: performance? minimum memory usage? least impact on garbage collector?  most compact code?  easiest to understand?  most use of built-in functions?  Without saying what the measurement criteria is, the question is basically meaningless because "preferred" has no meaning without a very specific context.  For example, if you were judging a contest among 5 submissions of preferred algorithms, what would be the exact quantitative criteria by which you would measure each submission?

Comment: @jfriend point taken. I will gladly rephrase as soon as I understand better. I meant performance since the native solution is already fine. Since a full new array gets generated anyway, I thought most typical sorting algorithm trade-offs were removed (memory and garbage).

Comment: @Hurelu _"Need to sort an array of floats into a new array without changing the source."_ Can include array of floats , expected result at Question ? Tried utilizing `Array.prototype.splice()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice ?

Comment: Since 80% of the comments so far suggested `.slice().sort()` which was already in the question I've significantly shortened the question to make it more concise. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 143):

There's a simpler syntax for immutably sorting an array using ES6 spread operator:

```
[...array].sort(sortFn)
```

Comment: Except that spread doesn't do a deep clone, so if it's an array of objects with many levels, you're kinda SOL with that.

Comment: @robertmain, actually, it's better that way. As sorting doesn't change the contained objects either. Cloning the containing objects would kill shallow comparisons in other places, making optimizations very hard.

Comment: It is still an in-place sort on the clone (ie clone then in-place sort the clone). The question is about the potential benefits of an out-of-place sort from source to target.

Comment: @s.meijer interesting!...iv always avoided a shallow clone on sorts for this reason but i never really thought about the fact that your not mutating the nested objects within that sort

Answer (score 62):

As the comments have repeated a few times:

1. `shuffledArray.slice().sort()` is the default way to go.
2. It's not really clear how we could have a better algorithm / method using the libraries your mentioned.

Seeing as the motivation for non-destructive sorting is related to writing functional code, and you're looking at Ramda...check out Facebook's ImmutableJS library if you haven't already.

Particularly, the `Seq`.
You could start storing your array of floats in a `Seq`, sort it, and be sure the original Seq remains in the right order.
In addition, it utilizes Lazy evaluation.
http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq
http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq/sortBy

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at the *immutable-js* source code and it also uses "clone then in-place native sort" just like *underscore*, *lodash* and *ramda*. Since the algorithm literature is quite focused on in-place sorting to reduce the memory requirements I thought removing that constraint would change things. All the feedback so far suggests not.

Answer (score 5):

Newer javascript runtime can use `Array.prototype.toSorted`

[Documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted)

```js
const months = ["Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Dec"];
const sortedMonths = months.toSorted();
console.log(sortedMonths); // ['Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Mar']
console.log(months); // ['Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec']

const values = [1, 10, 21, 2];
const sortedValues = values.toSorted((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(sortedValues); // [1, 2, 10, 21]
console.log(values); // [1, 10, 21, 2]
```

Comment: Yes. But it might just clone and do an in-place sort under the hood. I did a quick benchmark and `a.slice().sort( (a,b)=>a-b )` is surprisingly faster than `a.toSorted( (a,b)=>a-b )`. Sorting might be a rare case where more memory does not help and sorting is just always done in place.

Comment: @Hurelu IMHO, benchmarks on relatively new JavaScript built-in functions have limited significance. The new function's performance may well improve with any browser / JS engine update. For better readability and to clarify the intention to not modify the original array, I'd always recommend using `toSorted()`, if your setup allows to do so.